# How to avoid string interpolation in POST Url paramters?

Tags: java, rest, http, url, http-post

I am trying to send following parameter (same name with multiple values) with single key name. Also in my header I have headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); property as well.

```
requestData.put("scope", "openid&scope=profile&scope=email");
```

but on sever side this string is receiving in encoded format as below:

```
scope=openid%26scope%3Dprofile%26scope%3Demail
```

I want server to receive my paramters as  scope=openid&scope=profile&scope=email.

Request function:

```
@Override
public void getParams(Map<String, String> requestData) {

    requestData.put("scope", "openid&scope=profile&scope=email");

}
```

Comment: Hi, did you consider to use URLDecoder at server side? 
URLDecoder.decode("my encoded string", "UTF-8");

Comment: What you are trying to do is perfectly reasonable.  Given what you _are_ doing, the behavior you are seeing is exactly correct.  More code showing how you are what you are doing with the request data may help.  It might be, for instance, that you are using the wrong type for `requestData`, and something like a MultiMap might be more suitable for your use case.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason here is my request data function. I can not pass scope with separate key as it is Map<String, String> 
public void getParams(Map<String, String> requestData) {
                        requestData.put("scope", "openid&scope=profile&scope=email");
                    }

Comment: Note that request parameters allow for arrays, e.g. `scope=openid&scope=profile&scope=email` would be ok. Setting this in a Java client should be something like `requestData.put("scope", new String[]{"openid", "profile", "email");`. (Depends on what exactly you are doing, e.g. what is `requestData`?)

Comment: @Thomas please check the updated question. I am just sending above three scope parameters as my request data.

Comment: Well, with a `Map<String, String>` you don't have any choice but using one string. You could try using a value like `"openid,profile,email"` but I doubt the system will realize that you meant this to be an array so splitting that yourself might still be required. If you want to actually use an array we'd see more, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: @Thomas is there anyway to add header type: "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded as well as UTF-8?

Comment: Well, the [Content-Type header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) allows for the syntax `type; charset` so `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void getParams(Map<String, String> requestData) {
    requestData.put("scope", "openid&scope=profile&scope=email");
}
```

It is almost certainly the case that `java.util.Map` is not the data structure you want to be using here.  The behavior you are observing is precisely correct, given the way that url encoding of a Map is supposed to work, and you aren't going to be able to beat it by doing anything clever in the `getParams` method.

What you want is going to be something like a `Multiset`, or a `Map<String,List<String>` with some clever URI serialization code.

The presence of the `@Override` annotation is a bad sign -- it suggests that you may be handcuffed to an API that doesn't support the use case that you need.  You may need to tear up a lot of existing code to extend your solution to cover this case.

Comment: is there anyway to add header type:
"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded as well as UTF-8?